# Why Array reference assignation is not working in typescript?

Tags: angular

I am working on an application and I have one service and an component file(typescript file of a component in angular). What I am doing is performing search from IndexedDB(Browser) and assigning to Array of type any, but It is not working, code is given below:

Service typescript file:

```
// taking a empty array of type any
searchedHistoryArr = [];

// calling method from component typescript file  
searchHistoryFromIndexDb(): any[] {

  this.indexService.getAll('search', (data) => {
    if (data)
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.searchedHistoryArr.push(data[i]);
      }

    //console.log(data);

  });

  return this.searchedHistoryArr;
}
```

Component file : This file has some method and a line of code is written below.

```
historyArray=[];
// calling the method of service typescript file
this.historyArray= this.searchService.searchHistoryFromIndexDb()
```

Expected behaviour as per me: historyArray must have reference of returned 
 value;
 But HistoryArray still has length zero.

Comment: Try logging `this.searchService.searchHistoryFromIndexDb()` to the console to check what gets printed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return value from function which has Observable subscription inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291783/how-to-return-value-from-function-which-has-observable-subscription-inside)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 Call to service not returning data within form change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52045979/angular-6-call-to-service-not-returning-data-within-form-change)

Answer (score 0):

Your method `searchHistoryFromIndexDB` does not return an array with entries, because you're filling the array within a callback, which must not be executed synchronously.

Because i don't know your IndexedDB access implementation i suggest you following:

```
// taking a empty array of type any
searchedHistoryArr = [];

// calling method from component typescript file  
searchHistoryFromIndexDb(): Promise<any[]> {
    const arr: any[] = [];

    // Create a new promise, which you can resolve after the IndexedDB returns data
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.indexService.getAll('search', (data) => {
            if (data) {
                // Because data is an array, you can just resolve data
                resolve(data);                     
            } else { 
                // Maybe you want to reject the promise in case you don't receive some results
                reject('No data available');
            }
        });
    });
}

historyArray=[];
// calling the method of service typecript file
this.searchService.searchHistoryFromIndexDb().then((data) => {
    this.historyArray = data;
});
```